# Verilog Parameter & using \r\n

Tags: verilog, system-verilog, carriage-return

How do you enter a carriage-return and new-line? I can't see to find anything online that suggests this needs something unique. For example, if I do...

parameter [x:x] myString = "Hello \r\n world";

What actually ends up being put into myString is something like "Hello r\n world"

Does SystemVerilog need a special notation to handle something like this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Table 5-1 in the SystemVerilog 1800-2017 LRM does not list `\r` (carriage return) as one of the available special characters. This character is ignored by most display clients, but if you really need it you can use the hex code `\x0d` instead.